# Oracle to Unix time conversion

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

How to convert `oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP` to unix `TIME`?

I have a time value, let's say

`"22-DEC-18 02.25.18.288000000 PM"`

which is **oracle sql** `timestamps.

I have to convert it to **unix** `timestamp` in Java.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with Unix time? Do you mean the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00 GMT, or something else?

Comment: By unix timestamp i mean epoch time, which is in the long int format.               For "22-DEC-18 02.25.18.288000000 PM" Epoch timestamp will be 1545460200.

Comment: Milliseconds or seconds?

Comment: In Milliseconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that with unix time you mean the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00 GMT.

You can get this by getting a `java.sql.Timestamp` and using its `getTime()` method to get the number of **milli**seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00 GMT, then convert that to seconds.

You can get `java.sql.Timestamp` from an `oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP` using its `timestampValue()` method, but it would probably better to just use the JDBC defined API and get the `java.sql.Timestamp` directly instead of using the Oracle extension API.

For example:

```
oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP oracleTimestamp = // ...
java.sql.Timestamp jdbcTimestamp = oracleTimestamp.timestampValue();
long epochMillis = jdbcTimestamp.getTime();
long epochSeconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(epochMillis); // or just epochMillis / 1000;
```

If you want milliseconds, you can just skip the last step.